# Get Current Node in Drupal 8 in Controller that handle ajax request

Tags: drupal-8

I am trying to get current node in drupal 8 controller via \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node'), but it returns null. Is there way to get current node object in controller.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The "node object" parameter only available in node routes or you can specify  in routing.yml with:

```
path: '/node/{node}/example'
  options:
    parameters:
      node:
        type: 'entity:node'
```

The correct is you avoid get the node in this way, study the context, for example, in hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter you can access the node object using the variable $variables passed by hook.
If you should put on the node as object in the route like the node pages, just specify and pass in the route